# Silverlight 5 - How to implement mouse-look camera?

Tags: silverlight, 3d, applet, frame-rate

Is it possible to create a 3d first person perspective game with Silverlight 5?

Java applets can do it: for example Minecraft game using OpenGL. WebGL can't do it: see [How to implement mouselook in the browser?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/how-to-implement-mouselook-in-the-browser) question.

It would require ability to capture mouse: a) get relative mouse move every frame b) force mouse cursor to stay inside game window.

It's probably impossible but i'm posting to get attention on this problem on google search.